# Can we have an RSS feed for /tools/new-user-posts?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, moderation, feed

(NB: I had asked this over on meta.stackexchange.com, as [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6293/can-we-have-an-rss-feed-for-tools-new-user-posts). However, with the advent of StackExchange 2.0, meta.SE seems to have become redundant, so I'm moving it here.)

Background: I'm a moderator on mathoverflow.net. We're one of the most successful Stack Exchange 1.0 sites, and hope to migrate to 2.0.

The /tools/new-user-posts page (only accessible to moderators) is extremely useful for keeping a close eye on new users, especially during occasional troubles with trolls. Could we have an RSS feed for it?

Answer (score 2):

These are the kinds of things you'd have to migrate to SE 2.0 for, to align core engine features.

But yes, I would be interested in implementing a feature like this, in a way that all sites could benefit.